# Adding yes and no button for exit

Tags: android, eclipse

Below is a piece of code for exiting from the app when button2 is tapped.When the button is pressed a toast message for exiting the app is displayed.I want to include "yes" and "no"(confirmation buttons) in the toast.Can someone please tell me how to do that?

```
public void addListenerOnButton2()
{ 
    exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    exit.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            exme="Are you sure you want to quit?";
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,exme, 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
            t.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You want the buttons IN the toast message? You cannot do that.

Comment: do u really want toast to do that?

Comment: ya..I came to know that we can't do that in toast.Instead we can   to it in dialog..Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Instead you can use : AlertDialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MainActivity.this);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
              })
            .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }
```

Comment: I could not for the life of me remember the name of these. Fair play for such detail!

Answer (score 1):

just put below code inside your button click event

```
btnButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        MainActivity.this);

    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
        .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                exme="Ok button Pressed";
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,exme, 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
        t.show();
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
          })
        .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                exme1="Cancel button Pressed";
        Toast t1 = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,exme1, 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
        t1.show();
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Change it with your activity name, like if you have your activity name as a MainActivity then type MainActivity.this instead of context.

Comment: @user3035473, solved or not, if you are still facing any problem do comment here. happy to help you.

Comment: there is an error while creating alert dialog i.e. in  AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

Comment: U have to import alert dialog, just press ctrl + Shift + O, and you gotta go.

Comment: or else include "import android.app.AlertDialog;" (without double quote).

Comment: Now there is no errors but the code is not functioning as intended

Comment: then what's the problem you are getting, what is happening when you press button.

Comment: So I posted it with title as "Dialog box doesn't appear when EXIT button is clicked".

Comment: Do one thing just post your whole code here or just edit your question with full activity and xml file,so i can check and tell the necessary changes, or if possible i will edit the code.